# Description Reveal on Hover (CSS or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am trying to replicate the description reveal on hover seen on [this web page](https://globalcampus.uark.edu/directory/index.php)

I got sort of close by practicing with this example:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);

a.box {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #2f9b9b;
 display: block;
 width: 400px;
 height: 250px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.content {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0 4em;
 z-index: 2;
 height: 3em;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

a:hover .content {
 height: 8em;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

p {
 height: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 margin: 5px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 
}

a:hover p{
 height: 3em;
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

.link {
 height: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1.5;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 display: block;
 font-size: 0.85em;
 font-style: italic;
}

a:hover .link {
 transition: all .2s ease;
}

.description {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="box"> 
        <div class="content">
   <h2>
    DONALD JUDGES
   </h2>
      Vice Provost for Distance Education
   <p class="description">
        <br/>
        
    GLBL 505
        <br/>
        479-575-7571
        <br/>
      djudges@uark.edu
    <span class="link">Click to read more >> </span>
   </p>
   
     </div>
 </a>
```

The tough part for me is how they made the read area with text slide up in the first link when hovering over someone's picture, then back down like that in the process.

The source code was generated using Snap and does not make sense to me, plus I do not have access to Snap. I figure there must be a way to do it using CSS or Javascript

Any help please?

Comment: Please show the code that you have and what you've tried.

Comment: Hey Kirsch it looks like you forgot to link your example, please edit your post and add the example so we can assist you.

Comment: Thank you. Is the link included this time? I get confused working with posting links in the questions

Comment: Thanks for the edits Scott Marcus. Just noticed them a few minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me, they are using css hover `a:hover p` to get the additional information to show. Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mallettem/sr4rxpgz/) with a simplified version of the same thing working.

```
p {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

a:hover p{
 height: 3em;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```